# spring cloud:feign can't work with Consul

Tags: java, consul, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to set up a spring cloud project with Consul and Feign, but it doesn't work.

It always noties that "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: facility-readers".
Here is main class of consumer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my consumer Interface use Feign

```
@FeignClient("facility-readers")
public interface FacilitiesService {
@RequestMapping(value="/facilities/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String findByIdFeign();
}
```

Here is my consumer service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/facilities")
public class FacilitiesServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  private FacilitiesService facilitiesService;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getInfo() {
      String reult=facilitiesService.findByIdFeign();

      System.out.println("服务消费者");
      return reult;
  }
}
```

Here is consumer file application.yml

```
server:
  display-name: 设备写服务
  port: 8900
spring:
  application:
    name: facility-writer
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 192.168.8.164
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        register: true
        enabled: true
        instance-id: facility-${random.value}
        service-name: 设备写服务
      enabled: true
```

Here is my provider mian class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ImportResource("spring-context.xml")
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my provider service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/facilities")
public class FacilitiesQueryServiceImpl {

@RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getInfo() {
    System.out.println("服务提供方");
    return "调用成功";
}
}
```

Here is provider file application.yml

```
server:
  display-name: 设施业务读服务
  port: 8901
spring:
  application:
    name: facility-reader
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: 192.168.8.164
      port: 8500
      discovery:
        register: true
        enabled: true
        instance-id: facility-reader
        service-name: 设施业务读服务
      enabled: true
```

Here is pom.xml content

```
<dependencies>
<!-- Spring cloud -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
</dependency>
</dependency>
```

In this console noties

```
2017-04-21 14:13:31.347  INFO 18940 --- [ility-readers-1] c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: facility-readers.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
2017-04-21 14:13:31.386  INFO 18940 --- [ility-readers-1] c.n.u.concurrent.ShutdownEnabledTimer    : Shutdown hook installed for: NFLoadBalancer-PingTimer-facility-readers
2017-04-21 14:13:31.452  INFO 18940 --- [ility-readers-1] c.netflix.loadbalancer.BaseLoadBalancer  : Client:facility-readers instantiated a LoadBalancer:DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=facility-readers,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:null
2017-04-21 14:13:31.457  INFO 18940 --- [ility-readers-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : Using serverListUpdater PollingServerListUpdater
2017-04-21 14:13:31.607  INFO 18940 --- [ility-readers-1] c.n.l.DynamicServerListLoadBalancer      : DynamicServerListLoadBalancer for client facility-readers initialized: DynamicServerListLoadBalancer:{NFLoadBalancer:name=facility-readers,current list of Servers=[],Load balancer stats=Zone stats: {},Server stats: []}ServerList:ConsulServerList{serviceId='facility-readers', tag=null}
2017-04-21 14:13:31.872 ERROR 18940 --- [nio-8900-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: FacilitiesService#findByIdFeign() failed and no fallback available.] with root cause

com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: facility-readers
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10307) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10274) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:445) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:342) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.ribbon.LoadBalancerFeignClient.execute(LoadBalancerFeignClient.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:97) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76) ~[feign-core-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at feign.hystrix.HystrixInvocationHandler$1.run(HystrixInvocationHandler.java:108) ~[feign-hystrix-9.3.1.jar:na]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:301) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:51) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDefer.call(OnSubscribeDefer.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:41) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach.call(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10211) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:94) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:56) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction$1.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:47) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContexSchedulerAction.call(HystrixContexSchedulerAction.java:69) ~[hystrix-core-1.5.6.jar:1.5.6]
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.1.10.jar:1.1.10]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
```

What is wrong in my project ?

Comment: Have you used the DiscoveryClient in yrou client? https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-consul.adoc#using-the-discoveryclient

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found the stupid reason why this was happening : I thought that importing Feign would be enough. But actually I was missing this dependency :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

(don't forget the STARTER in the name )

Once I used it, I saw that 10s after my app started up, some Consul related activity in the logs was happening, even without doing anything, which was a good sign. Then I confirmed it was working as expected.

Comment: We're using `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.instance-zone` with all services registered in Consul, but not sure how to filter from client to ensure discoverable services are dev only, qa only,  or prod only; did you figure that out?